# codeigniter Undefined property: Introduce::$upload error

Tags: php, codeigniter

here is my file upload process

```
// file upload process      


$config['upload_path'] = UPLOAD_PATH ."/introduce/";
    $config['allowed_types'] = UPLOAD_ALLOW_EXT;
    $config['max_size'] = '10240';
    $config['file_name'] = time();                  
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    foreach($_FILES as $key => $value) 
    {
        if($_FILES[$key]['name'])
        {       
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($key)) 
             {
                var_dump($this->upload->display_errors());
                alert('erro while file upload');
            } else {
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                ${$key} = $_FILES[$key]['name'];
                ${"o".$key} = $upload_data['file_name'];
            }
        }
    }
```

I have same code.
worked in "**/controller/1.php**" 
deosn't work in "**/controller/2.php**"

**error massage**

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   property: Introduce::$upload Filename: admmode/introduce.php Line
>   Number: 77
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function do_upload() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/html/application/controllers/admmode/introduce.php on line 77

Comment: 77 line number means which line are indicate please?

Comment: if (!$this->upload->do_upload($key))  this line. I can't find solution....

Comment: also "$this->upload->do_upload('filename1');" deosn't work too.

Comment: remove $key and check please remove extra jquery code from Ci you can alert with echo

Comment: I already did it.
point is "Undefined property: Introduce::$upload".

Comment: i did 'echo $this->upload->display_errors();' same error showing

Comment: are you add multiple images?

Comment: Have you loaded upload library?

Comment: Yes, I loaded upload library.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller/2.php are your sure you loaded the upload library?

```
$this->load->library('upload')
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to application/config/autoload.php and add the 'upload' library like this :

> $autoload['libraries'] = array('database',...,'upload');